# HTML Input-Attribute "required" only for one button

Tags: html

I've got an file-input which is submitted with a submit button. But theres also a delete button in the same form. So my problem is, when i press the delete button it will say "Please select an file" because the "required" attribute is in the file-input. I want that this message only displays when you press the upload button(of course only if the input is empty).

Here's my Code :

```
<form>
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" required>
<input type="submit" name="sub_image" value="Upload">
<input type="submit" name="del_image" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make sense: Delete which file - the one you are about to upload???

Comment: Thanks @j08691 Sometimes its just so simple that you didnt even thought about that :D

Comment: In addition to @j08691 comment, are you trying to reset the file selection? If that's the case then set `type="reset"` for `del_image` input. Also, using `<button>` instead of `<input>` is even better.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **formnovalidate** attribute to skip validation on specific submit button:

```
<form>
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" required>
<input type="submit" name="sub_image" value="Upload">
<input type="submit" name="del_image" value="Delete" formnovalidate >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function ($) {
 
    $('#my-form').validate({
        rules: {},
        messages: {},
        submitHandler: function () {
            return false
        }
    });
    $('#del_image').click(function(){
 
  $("#file").val("");
 });
    

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="my-form">
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" required>
<input type="submit" name="sub_image" value="Upload">

<button id="del_image">Delete</button>
</form>
```